# Formulas formed using concatenation don't calculate/activate unless manually entered

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Long story short, I have two sheets, one is 'Raw Data' and the other is 'Results'.  I am trying to get the results sheet to pull the text or number from every seventh row of my 'Raw Data' sheet, so A1 in 'Results' would be A1 in Raw Data, A2 in 'Results' would A8 in 'Raw Data', A3 in 'Results' would be A15 in 'Raw Data'.

I used a concatenate function in a separate sheet to develop the formulas for each cell in the results sheet, so A1 in Results is `='Raw Data'!A1` , A2 in Results is `='Raw Data'!A8` and so on.  When I copied the formulas and pasted them in (using paste values), excel recognizes them as text, not formulas.  Currently the only solution I've found is clicking each one and hitting Enter, activating the formula.  But I cannot find a way to do that for whole sheet, just individual cells.

Things I have tried:  I tried formatting the cells to General and Using Calculate Now in the Calculation options.  Neither did the trick.

Any help is welcome, this is my first post here,

Thank you,
-J.

Comment: I don't know if this will actually solve your issue, but I've encountered similar behavior with formulas and mine all update if I save the file.  Might be worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, the formula you want in cell A1 of Results is:

`=OFFSET('Raw Data'!A1,ROW()*7-7,0)`

- In row 1 of Results, `ROW()` returns 1, so `ROW()*7-7` is 0. 0 Rows and 0 columns offset from 'Raw Data'!A1 is 'Raw Data'!A1.
- In row 2 of Results, `ROW()` returns 2, so `ROW()*7-7` is 7. 7 rows and 0 columns offset from 'Raw Data'!A1 is 'Raw Data'!A8.

Answer (score 0):

The following hack-ish workaround just might work:

Highlight all the cells you've just pasted to. Right now, they are all strings, right? Press <kbd>Ctrl-H</kbd>. This should open up the `Replace` dialog. Try replacing all `='Raw Data'!` with the same string: `='Raw Data'!`. This will replace all of them and will force them to calculate, not different from manually editing each of them. See the following screenshot for my attempt:

[image]

Also, I might be a bit off, but I don't think concatenation is your best option. I'm guessing a correct application of the `OFFSET` formula can achieve what you want.

Comment: Yes indeed on the use of OFFSET.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using INDIRECT(ReferenceString)?

This works for me when C1 has "Sheet2" and D1 has "A1", it picks up value in Sheet2 cell A1

```
=INDIRECT("'"&C1&"'!"&D1)
```

Comment: Please post this as a comment. The answer field should not be used to confirm or clarify.

Comment: @Ken Still, as Nanashi has previously stated, your post would be better suited as a comment (unless you add additional details).

Comment: @Sam you are confused.  Nanashi was referring to the original post which I had neglected to paste the rest of the answer.  It was just the first line of the post.